# react js boolean value comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react javascript code.
I am looping through a set of boolean values.
When 'data.nextrow' is false, i want nextrow1 to be false too but it is getting set to true.

```
    console.log("before nextrow:",data.nextrow); **prints false**
    let nextrow1 = data.nextrow ? data.nextrow : true;
    console.log("after nextrow:",nextrow1); **prints true**
```

I am expecting nextrow1 to be set to FALSE

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be set to `false`? The code you posted cannot possibly do that.

Comment: Also make sure the value of `data.nextrow` is not the **string** "false", as the string "false" is not `false`.

Comment: When 'data.nextrow' is false, i want nextrow1 to be false too but it is getting set to true. its purse false. gets printed in blue in the console

Comment: `a ? b : c` means "if `a` tests as `true` then the result should be `b`, otherwise `c`"

Comment: a ? b : c ,  if a is null,  take c. if a exists, take b. that's what i want.

Comment: Well `? :` does not work that way. And if your code really is as you posted in the question, the result is not possible. There's not enough context to know for sure however.

Comment: if data.nextrow= true, this will change for true, and if data.nextrow = false, this will change for true - so always data.nextrow will be true(in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!!` convention

```
let nextrow1 = !!data.nextrow;
```

This will work if `data.nextrow` is some falsy value (`0`, `false`, `""`, `null`), not the string `"false"`.

Comment: Though I'd suggest sticking to `Boolean(data.nextrow)` in code meant for humans and let the machine (minifier) turn that into `!!data.nextrow`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so

> data.nextrow ? data.nextrow : true;

this is **[expression evaluation](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/expressionevaluation/)**

---

One of using it is **[conditional rendering](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react)**

```
If data.nextrow is true = render all after ?
If data.nextrow is false = render all after :
```

---

For changing variable(true -> false & false -> true)

You can just use:

```
function App() {

  const [isTrue, setisTrue] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setisTrue(!isTrue)}>Click for change boolean</button>
      {isTrue ? <h1>Now isTrue is true</h1> : <h1>Now isTrue is False</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not "conditional rendering", it's a plain JavaScript ternary expression. There's no rendering involved; it's just expression evaluation.

Comment: a ? b : c ,     if a is null,  take c. if a exists, take b. that's what i want.

Comment: That's right, so conditional rendering is simply the option of implementing expression evaluation

Comment: if(a === null){setState(c)}(if a !== null){setState(b)}

Answer (score 0):

i acheive my goal in the following lines. if it can be done in 1 line, let me know. data.nextrow can be possibly null.

```
nextrow1  = false;
if(data.nextrow !== null){
        if(data.nextrow === false){
            nextrow1  = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to account for `null` in that way (ie `null` != `false`) you could do a one-liner like this:

```
nextrow1 = !(data.nextrow !== null && data.nextrow === false)
```

This will set nextrow1 to `false` if data.nextrow is `null`

```
nextrow1 = data.nextrow === null ? data.nextrow : !(data.nextrow === false)
```

This will set nextrow1 to `null` if data.nextrow is `null`